# TextDrawable - getSupportActionBar.setLogo(Drawable drawable) not works

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, toolbar, android-toolbar

I would like to put a logo in my toolbar with a custom drawable from https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable.

But this code displays nothing

`TextDrawable drawable = TextDrawable.builder()
                .buildRound("A", Color.RED);
 getSupportActionBar().setLogo(drawable);`

But if I try with a "normal" drawable, it works.

```
getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** Solution added in comment by Mike M. works good, but looks bad:

[image]

Here's a code of this solution:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
TextDrawable drawable = TextDrawable.builder().beginConfig().width(40).height(40).endConfig()
        .buildRound("A", Color.RED);
toolbar.setLogo(drawable);
```

> NOTE: In this solution you need to set `width()` and `height()` of your `TextDrawable` logo, as it has as default value `-1`. Without that you won't see your `TextDrawable` icon.
>
> That's because of that the `Toolbar` class creates `logo` dynamically with `wrap_content` parameters.
>
> `TextDrawable` takes width and height of your `ImageView`, so please DON'T use `wrap_content` value, otherwise it would get default `-1` value and you won't see your image.
>
> Instead of it, set hard-coded value like in an example below, `match_parent` or use `layout_weight` to set how big your `TextDrawable` you want.

#### Here's my solution - create a TextDrawable logo using custom toolbar

1. Create a custom layout with name `action_bar.xml`
2. Put into it this code

   ```
   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/image_view"
       android:layout_width="32dp"
       android:layout_height="32dp"
       tools:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:paddingLeft="10dp"
       android:text="@string/app_name"
       android:textColor="#ffffff"
       android:textSize="24sp"
       android:textAlignment="gravity"
       android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
   ```
3. Add to your `onCreate` method in `MainActivity` class this code:

   ```
   //SET A DRAWABLE TO IMAGEVIEW
   Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
   setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
   getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_main);

   TextDrawable drawable = TextDrawable.builder()
           .buildRound("A", getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
   ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
   imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
   ```
4. After changes it should look like:

[image]

Hope it help

Comment: I've already edited my post. As you can see, you don't need to use `beginConfig()` method. Just set dimens of your `ImageView` and add it to custom toolbar layout. It would give you more possibilities and nice look :-)